# How to equate characters using switch case in java?

Tags: java

I want to use letters for the choices instead of numbers. So it would be R for free parking, C for covered parking and G for garage parking. I've tried to convert it over to an if statement but can't seem to figure out how to get it to work any help would be appreciated.

```
    /*get users parking choice*/
    System.out.println("What kind of parking would you like press 1 for free parking, " +
            " 2 for a Covered parking, or 3 for garage parking" );
    parking = garageType.nextInt();

    switch (parking){
        case 1:
            type = "free";
            gPrice = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            type = "covered";
            gPrice = 3000;
            break;
        case 3:
            type = "garage";
            gPrice = 6000;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("That was an invalid option please try again");
            break;
    }
    /* get total price*/
    total = condoPrice+gPrice;
    /*show the user their choices and condo, parking and total price*/
    System.out.println("You have selected a condo with a view of the "
            + view + " for $" + condoPrice + " with " + type + " parking, " +
            " your total for this condo and parking is $ " + total);
}
```

Comment: Just do `garageType.nextChar()`, and then change the cases to `'R'`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use characters as your decision making parameters, you need to take character as an input from the user.

Currently you are taking integer as an input

```
nextChar()
```

you can use this function to read a character and then compare it by keeping your decisions in a single quote like 'R'

Hope it Helps !

Answer (score 4):

```
     System.out.println("What kind of parking would you like press 'R' for free parking, " +
            " 'C' for a Covered parking, or 'G' for garage parking" );
    parking = garageType.nextChar();

    switch (parking){
        case 'R':
            type = "free";
            gPrice = 0;
            break;
        case 'C':
            type = "covered";
            gPrice = 3000;
            break;
        case 'G':
            type = "garage";
            gPrice = 6000;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("That was an invalid option please try again");
            break;
    }
    /* get total price*/
    total = condoPrice+gPrice;
    /*show the user their choices and condo, parking and total price*/
    System.out.println("You have selected a condo with a view of the "
            + view + " for $" + condoPrice + " with " + type + " parking, " +
            " your total for this condo and parking is $ " + total);
}
```

Comment: any time. if it answers your problem, you can accept it as an answer :)